# How to use alias a method based on input from user

Tags: ruby

How can i change the following code without using eval. Is there a way i can alias the getroot function based on argument when initializing the Heap.

```
class Heap

  def initialize arr,type=:min
     newfunc = "get#{type.to_s}".to_sym
     eval ("class << self; alias #{newfunc} :getroot; end")
  end

  def getroot     
     puts "Inside Getroot"
  end

end

a = Heap.new([1,2,3],:max)
a.getmax                      #prints Inside Getroot

b = Heap.new([1,2,3],:min)
b.getmin                      #prints Inside Getroot
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this satisfactory?

```
class Heap
  def initialize arr, type=:min
    newfunc = "get#{type.to_s}".to_sym
    self.class.class_eval {alias_method newfunc, :getroot}
  end
  def getroot
    puts "Inside Getroot"
  end
end
```